# subTables join query, any database midware suggestions

Tags: mysql, database

I have a big table named 'Order', I separate it to n subtables(named 'Order_1', 'Order_2'...) in a MySQL server. Then I need do a sql query, such as 'select * from Order(logic table) join User where User.status=0'. 
any database midware suggestions? I tried MyCat, but it didn't do work.

Comment: Why are you splitting it? It makes queries really horrible. What MySQL version? The right indexes will make a lookup fast.

Comment: @danblack the order'size is more than 12,000,000, and it's growing everyday. MySQL version is 5.6.16-log.

Comment: rows I assume. Provided your query looks up by index I don't see problem. I assume your query contains other where criteria. What are your current problems?

Comment: You are possibly looking for Partitioning: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html